# Output value on dashboard using Dash (from Plotly) after entering values for variables

Tags: python, callback, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard where I have a series of variables, 12 to be specific, and I am trying to run a machine learning prediction model for property prices. I am using for this example only some of the variables to output a prediction based on a linear regression model. So far so good, the input variables look good, the stylesheet is working... BUT, the output generated by the python function just prints it on the screen right below the "Generate Prediction" button. I added some additional code to see if I can have this value printed in an dbc.Input() component with no luck, now nothing is outputed into the dashboard. I want to be able to control de style and position of this output but I don't know how. I will include my code below:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG]) #Use also SPACELAB / CYBORG
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    
    dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.Br(),
                    ),
            ),
    dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.H2('Price Predictor Tool'),
                    width={'size': 12, 'offset':1},
                    ),
            ),
    dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.Br(),
                    ),
            ),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.P('Bedrooms'),
                    width={'size': 1, 'offset':1},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Bathrooms'),
                    width={'size': 1, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Half Baths'),
                    width={'size': 1, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Garage Spots'),
                    width={'size': 1, 'offset':0},
                    ),
        dbc.Col(html.P('Year Built'),
                    width={'size': 1, 'offset':0},
                    ), 
        dbc.Col(html.P('Type of Floors'),
                    width={'size': 2, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Waterfront Description'),
                    width={'size': 2, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         ], no_gutters=False
        ),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-bed',
            placeholder='Number',
            options=[ 
                {'label': '1', 'value': 1},
                {'label': '2', 'value': 2},
                {'label': '3', 'value': 3},
                {'label': '4', 'value': 4},
                {'label': '5', 'value': 5},
                {'label': '6', 'value': 6},
                {'label': '7', 'value': 7},
                {'label': '8', 'value': 8},
                {'label': '9', 'value': 9},
                {'label': '10', 'value': 10},
                {'label': '11', 'value': 11},
                {'label': '12', 'value': 12},
                {'label': '12+', 'value': 13}]),
            width={'size':1,'offset':1}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-bath',
            placeholder='Number',
            options=[ 
                {'label': '1', 'value': 1},
                {'label': '2', 'value': 2},
                {'label': '3', 'value': 3},
                {'label': '4', 'value': 4},
                {'label': '5', 'value': 5},
                {'label': '6', 'value': 6},
                {'label': '7', 'value': 7},
                {'label': '8', 'value': 8},
                {'label': '9', 'value': 9},
                {'label': '10', 'value': 10},
                {'label': '11', 'value': 11},
                {'label': '12', 'value': 12},
                {'label': '12+', 'value': 13}]),
            width={'size':1,'offset':0}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-hbath',
            placeholder='Number',
            options=[ 
                {'label': 'None', 'value': 0},
                {'label': '1 or more', 'value': 1}]),
            width={'size':1,'offset':0}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-garage',
            placeholder='Number',
            options=[ 
                {'label': 'None', 'value': 0},
                {'label': '1', 'value': 1},
                {'label': '2 or more', 'value': 2}]),
            width={'size':1,'offset':0}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-built_year',
            placeholder='Year',
            options=[
                {'label': '2021', 'value': 2021},
                {'label': '2020', 'value': 2020},
                {'label': '2019', 'value': 2019},
                {'label': '2018', 'value': 2018},
                {'label': '2017', 'value': 2017},
                {'label': '2016', 'value': 2016},
                {'label': '2015', 'value': 2015},
                {'label': '2014', 'value': 2014},
                {'label': '2013', 'value': 2013},
                {'label': '2012', 'value': 2012},
                {'label': '2011', 'value': 2011},
                {'label': '2010', 'value': 2010},
                {'label': '2009', 'value': 2009},
                {'label': '2008', 'value': 2008},
                {'label': '2007', 'value': 2007},
                {'label': '2006', 'value': 2006},
                {'label': '2005', 'value': 2005},
                {'label': '2004', 'value': 2004},
                {'label': '2003', 'value': 2003},
                {'label': '2002', 'value': 2002},
                {'label': '2001', 'value': 2001},
                {'label': '2000', 'value': 2000},
                {'label': '1999', 'value': 1999},
                {'label': '1998', 'value': 1998},
                {'label': '1997', 'value': 1997},
                {'label': '1996', 'value': 1996},
                {'label': '1995', 'value': 1995},
                {'label': '1994', 'value': 1994},
                {'label': '1993', 'value': 1993},
                {'label': '1992', 'value': 1992},
                {'label': '1991', 'value': 1991},
                {'label': '1990', 'value': 1990},
                {'label': '1989', 'value': 1989},
                {'label': '1988', 'value': 1988},
                {'label': '1987', 'value': 1987},
                {'label': '1986', 'value': 1986},
                {'label': '1985', 'value': 1985},
                {'label': '1984', 'value': 1984},
                {'label': '1983', 'value': 1983},
                {'label': '1982', 'value': 1982},
                {'label': '1981', 'value': 1981},
                {'label': '1980', 'value': 1980},
                {'label': '1979', 'value': 1979},
                {'label': '1978', 'value': 1978},
                {'label': '1977', 'value': 1977},
                {'label': '1976', 'value': 1976},
                {'label': '1975', 'value': 1975},
                {'label': '1974', 'value': 1974},
                {'label': '1973', 'value': 1973},
                {'label': '1972', 'value': 1972},
                {'label': '1971', 'value': 1971},
                {'label': '1970', 'value': 1970},
                {'label': '1969', 'value': 1969},
                {'label': '1968', 'value': 1968},
                {'label': '1967', 'value': 1967},
                {'label': '1966', 'value': 1966},
                {'label': '1965', 'value': 1965},
                {'label': '1964', 'value': 1964},
                {'label': '1963', 'value': 1963},
                {'label': '1962', 'value': 1962},
                {'label': '1961', 'value': 1961},
                {'label': '1960', 'value': 1960},
                {'label': '1959', 'value': 1959},
                {'label': '1958', 'value': 1958},
                {'label': '1957', 'value': 1957},
                {'label': '1956', 'value': 1956},
                {'label': '1955', 'value': 1955},
                {'label': '1954', 'value': 1954},
                {'label': '1953', 'value': 1953},
                {'label': '1952', 'value': 1952},
                {'label': '1951', 'value': 1951},
                {'label': '1950', 'value': 1950},
                {'label': '1949', 'value': 1949},
                {'label': '1948', 'value': 1948},
                {'label': '1947', 'value': 1947},
                {'label': '1946', 'value': 1946},
                {'label': '1945', 'value': 1945},
                {'label': '1944', 'value': 1944},
                {'label': '1943', 'value': 1943},
                {'label': '1942', 'value': 1942},
                {'label': '1941', 'value': 1941},
                {'label': '1940', 'value': 1940},
                {'label': '1939', 'value': 1939},
                {'label': '1938', 'value': 1938},
                {'label': '1937', 'value': 1937},
                {'label': '1936', 'value': 1936},
                {'label': '1935', 'value': 1935},
                {'label': '1934', 'value': 1934},
                {'label': '1933', 'value': 1933},
                {'label': '1932', 'value': 1932},
                {'label': '1931', 'value': 1931},
                {'label': '1930', 'value': 1930},
                {'label': '1929', 'value': 1929},
                {'label': '1928', 'value': 1928},
                {'label': '1927', 'value': 1927},
                {'label': '1926', 'value': 1926},
                {'label': '1925', 'value': 1925},
                {'label': '1924', 'value': 1924},
                {'label': '1923', 'value': 1923},
                {'label': '1922', 'value': 1922},
                {'label': '1921', 'value': 1921},
                {'label': '1920', 'value': 1920},
                {'label': '1919', 'value': 1919},
                {'label': '1918', 'value': 1918},
                {'label': '1917', 'value': 1917},
                {'label': '1916', 'value': 1916},
                {'label': '1915', 'value': 1915},
                {'label': '1914', 'value': 1914},
                {'label': '1913', 'value': 1913},
                {'label': '1912', 'value': 1912},
                {'label': '1911', 'value': 1911},
                {'label': '1910', 'value': 1910},
                {'label': '1909', 'value': 1909},
                {'label': '1908', 'value': 1908},
                {'label': '1907', 'value': 1907},
                {'label': '1906', 'value': 1906},
                {'label': '1905', 'value': 1905},
                {'label': '1904', 'value': 1904},
                {'label': '1903', 'value': 1903},
                {'label': '1902', 'value': 1902},
                {'label': '1901', 'value': 1901},
                {'label': '1900', 'value': 1900}]),
            width={'size':1,'offset':0}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-floor',
            placeholder='Select all that apply',
            options=[
                {'label': 'Marble', 'value': 'Marble'},
                {'label': 'Vinyl', 'value': 'Vinyl'},
                {'label': 'Ceramic', 'value': 'Ceramic'},
                {'label': 'Carpeted', 'value': 'Carpeted'},
                {'label': 'Tile', 'value': 'Tile'},
                {'label': 'Other', 'value': 'Other'}],
            value=[],
            multi=True),
            width={'size':2,'offset':0}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-waterfront',
            placeholder='Select all that apply',
            options=[ 
                {'label': 'Ocean Front', 'value': 'Ocean Front'},
                {'label': 'Intracoastal Front', 'value': 'Intracoastal Front'},
                {'label': 'No Fixed Bridges', 'value': 'No Fixed Bridges'},
                {'label': 'Bay Front', 'value': 'Bay Front'},
                {'label': 'Fixed Bridges(s)', 'value': 'Fixed Bridges(s)'},
                {'label': 'Canal Front ', 'value': 'Canal Front '}],
            value=[],
            multi=True),
            width={'size':2,'offset':0,}
    ),
    ], no_gutters=False
        ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
     dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col(html.P('Living Area (Sq Ft)'),
                    width={'size': 2, 'offset':1},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Lot Area (Sq Ft)'),
                    width={'size': 2, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Zip Code'),
                    width={'size': 1, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Listing Starting Date'),
                    width={'size': 2, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         dbc.Col(html.P('Projected Days on the Market'),
                    width={'size': 2, 'offset':0},
                    ),
         ], no_gutters=False
        ),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(
            dbc.Input(id='input-living_area', type='number', 
                      placeholder='From 400 to 15000', 
                      min=400, max=15000, step=1, className='mb-3'),
            width={'size':2, 'offset':1},
            ),
        dbc.Col(
            dbc.Input(id='input-lot_area', type='number', 
                      placeholder='From 400+', 
                      min=400, max=15000, step=1, className='mb-3'),
            width={'size':2, 'offset':0},
            ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-zip_code',
            placeholder='33131',
            options=[ 
                {'label': '33498', 'value': 33498},
                {'label': '33496', 'value': 33496},
                {'label': '33493', 'value': 33493},
                {'label': '33487', 'value': 33487},
                {'label': '33486', 'value': 33486},
                {'label': '33484', 'value': 33484},
                {'label': '33483', 'value': 33483},
                {'label': '33480', 'value': 33480},
                {'label': '33478', 'value': 33478},
                {'label': '33477', 'value': 33477},
                {'label': '33476', 'value': 33476},
                {'label': '33473', 'value': 33473},
                {'label': '33472', 'value': 33472},
                {'label': '33470', 'value': 33470},
                {'label': '33469', 'value': 33469},
                {'label': '33467', 'value': 33467},
                {'label': '33463', 'value': 33463},
                {'label': '33462', 'value': 33462},
                {'label': '33461', 'value': 33461},
                {'label': '33460', 'value': 33460},
                {'label': '33458', 'value': 33458},
                {'label': '33449', 'value': 33449},
                {'label': '33446', 'value': 33446},
                {'label': '33445', 'value': 33445},
                {'label': '33444', 'value': 33444},
                {'label': '33442', 'value': 33442},
                {'label': '33441', 'value': 33441},
                {'label': '33438', 'value': 33438},
                {'label': '33437', 'value': 33437},
                {'label': '33436', 'value': 33436},
                {'label': '33435', 'value': 33435},
                {'label': '33434', 'value': 33434},
                {'label': '33433', 'value': 33433},
                {'label': '33432', 'value': 33432},
                {'label': '33431', 'value': 33431},
                {'label': '33430', 'value': 33430},
                {'label': '33428', 'value': 33428},
                {'label': '33426', 'value': 33426},
                {'label': '33418', 'value': 33418},
                {'label': '33417', 'value': 33417},
                {'label': '33415', 'value': 33415},
                {'label': '33414', 'value': 33414},
                {'label': '33413', 'value': 33413},
                {'label': '33412', 'value': 33412},
                {'label': '33411', 'value': 33411},
                {'label': '33410', 'value': 33410},
                {'label': '33409', 'value': 33409},
                {'label': '33408', 'value': 33408},
                {'label': '33407', 'value': 33407},
                {'label': '33406', 'value': 33406},
                {'label': '33405', 'value': 33405},
                {'label': '33404', 'value': 33404},
                {'label': '33403', 'value': 33403},
                {'label': '33401', 'value': 33401},
                {'label': '33351', 'value': 33351},
                {'label': '33334', 'value': 33334},
                {'label': '33332', 'value': 33332},
                {'label': '33331', 'value': 33331},
                {'label': '33330', 'value': 33330},
                {'label': '33328', 'value': 33328},
                {'label': '33327', 'value': 33327},
                {'label': '33326', 'value': 33326},
                {'label': '33325', 'value': 33325},
                {'label': '33324', 'value': 33324},
                {'label': '33323', 'value': 33323},
                {'label': '33322', 'value': 33322},
                {'label': '33321', 'value': 33321},
                {'label': '33319', 'value': 33319},
                {'label': '33317', 'value': 33317},
                {'label': '33316', 'value': 33316},
                {'label': '33315', 'value': 33315},
                {'label': '33314', 'value': 33314},
                {'label': '33313', 'value': 33313},
                {'label': '33312', 'value': 33312},
                {'label': '33311', 'value': 33311},
                {'label': '33309', 'value': 33309},
                {'label': '33308', 'value': 33308},
                {'label': '33306', 'value': 33306},
                {'label': '33305', 'value': 33305},
                {'label': '33304', 'value': 33304},
                {'label': '33301', 'value': 33301},
                {'label': '33196', 'value': 33196},
                {'label': '33194', 'value': 33194},
                {'label': '33193', 'value': 33193},
                {'label': '33190', 'value': 33190},
                {'label': '33189', 'value': 33189},
                {'label': '33187', 'value': 33187},
                {'label': '33186', 'value': 33186},
                {'label': '33185', 'value': 33185},
                {'label': '33184', 'value': 33184},
                {'label': '33183', 'value': 33183},
                {'label': '33182', 'value': 33182},
                {'label': '33181', 'value': 33181},
                {'label': '33180', 'value': 33180},
                {'label': '33179', 'value': 33179},
                {'label': '33178', 'value': 33178},
                {'label': '33177', 'value': 33177},
                {'label': '33176', 'value': 33176},
                {'label': '33175', 'value': 33175},
                {'label': '33174', 'value': 33174},
                {'label': '33173', 'value': 33173},
                {'label': '33172', 'value': 33172},
                {'label': '33170', 'value': 33170},
                {'label': '33169', 'value': 33169},
                {'label': '33168', 'value': 33168},
                {'label': '33167', 'value': 33167},
                {'label': '33166', 'value': 33166},
                {'label': '33165', 'value': 33165},
                {'label': '33162', 'value': 33162},
                {'label': '33161', 'value': 33161},
                {'label': '33160', 'value': 33160},
                {'label': '33158', 'value': 33158},
                {'label': '33157', 'value': 33157},
                {'label': '33156', 'value': 33156},
                {'label': '33155', 'value': 33155},
                {'label': '33154', 'value': 33154},
                {'label': '33150', 'value': 33150},
                {'label': '33149', 'value': 33149},
                {'label': '33147', 'value': 33147},
                {'label': '33146', 'value': 33146},
                {'label': '33145', 'value': 33145},
                {'label': '33144', 'value': 33144},
                {'label': '33143', 'value': 33143},
                {'label': '33142', 'value': 33142},
                {'label': '33141', 'value': 33141},
                {'label': '33140', 'value': 33140},
                {'label': '33139', 'value': 33139},
                {'label': '33138', 'value': 33138},
                {'label': '33137', 'value': 33137},
                {'label': '33136', 'value': 33136},
                {'label': '33135', 'value': 33135},
                {'label': '33134', 'value': 33134},
                {'label': '33133', 'value': 33133},
                {'label': '33132', 'value': 33132},
                {'label': '33131', 'value': 33131},
                {'label': '33130', 'value': 33130},
                {'label': '33129', 'value': 33129},
                {'label': '33128', 'value': 33128},
                {'label': '33127', 'value': 33127},
                {'label': '33126', 'value': 33126},
                {'label': '33125', 'value': 33125},
                {'label': '33122', 'value': 33122},
                {'label': '33109', 'value': 33109},
                {'label': '33101', 'value': 33101},
                {'label': '33076', 'value': 33076},
                {'label': '33073', 'value': 33073},
                {'label': '33071', 'value': 33071},
                {'label': '33069', 'value': 33069},
                {'label': '33068', 'value': 33068},
                {'label': '33067', 'value': 33067},
                {'label': '33066', 'value': 33066},
                {'label': '33065', 'value': 33065},
                {'label': '33064', 'value': 33064},
                {'label': '33063', 'value': 33063},
                {'label': '33062', 'value': 33062},
                {'label': '33060', 'value': 33060},
                {'label': '33056', 'value': 33056},
                {'label': '33055', 'value': 33055},
                {'label': '33054', 'value': 33054},
                {'label': '33039', 'value': 33039},
                {'label': '33035', 'value': 33035},
                {'label': '33034', 'value': 33034},
                {'label': '33033', 'value': 33033},
                {'label': '33032', 'value': 33032},
                {'label': '33031', 'value': 33031},
                {'label': '33030', 'value': 33030},
                {'label': '33029', 'value': 33029},
                {'label': '33028', 'value': 33028},
                {'label': '33027', 'value': 33027},
                {'label': '33026', 'value': 33026},
                {'label': '33025', 'value': 33025},
                {'label': '33024', 'value': 33024},
                {'label': '33023', 'value': 33023},
                {'label': '33021', 'value': 33021},
                {'label': '33020', 'value': 33020},
                {'label': '33019', 'value': 33019},
                {'label': '33018', 'value': 33018},
                {'label': '33016', 'value': 33016},
                {'label': '33015', 'value': 33015},
                {'label': '33014', 'value': 33014},
                {'label': '33013', 'value': 33013},
                {'label': '33012', 'value': 33012},
                {'label': '33010', 'value': 33010},
                {'label': '33009', 'value': 33009},
                {'label': '33004', 'value': 33004}]),
            width={'size':1,'offset':0}
    ),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-selling_month',
            placeholder='Select Month',
            options=[ 
                {'label': 'January', 'value': 1},
                {'label': 'February', 'value': 2},
                {'label': 'March', 'value': 3},
                {'label': 'April', 'value': 4},
                {'label': 'May', 'value': 5},
                {'label': 'June', 'value': 6},
                {'label': 'July', 'value': 7},
                {'label': 'August', 'value': 8},
                {'label': 'September', 'value': 9},
                {'label': 'October', 'value': 10},
                {'label': 'November', 'value': 11},
                {'label': 'December', 'value': 12}]),
            width={'size':2,'offset':0}
    ),
           dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='input-dom',
            placeholder='Select between 30, 60 and 90',
            options=[ 
                {'label': '30', 'value': 30},
                {'label': '60', 'value': 60},
                {'label': '90', 'value': 90}]),
            width={'size':2,'offset':0}
    ),
        
    ], no_gutters=False
        ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(
                [
        dbc.Button('Generate Prediction', id='input-predi_button', n_clicks=0, color='primary', className="mr-2"),
        html.Span(id="input-prediction", style={"vertical-align": "middle"}),
    ],
    width={'size':6,'offset':1}
    ),
        ], no_gutters=True
        ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(dbc.FormGroup(dbc.FormGroup(
    [
        dbc.Label("Property's Price Prediction", html_for="text-prediction", width={'size':2,'offset':1}),
        dbc.Col(
            dbc.Input(
                id='result', placeholder=""
            ),
            width={'size':1,'offset':0},
        ),
    ], row=True,
    )))
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('result', 'children'),
    [Input('input-predi_button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('input-bed', 'value'),
      State('input-bath', 'value'),
      State('input-hbath', 'value'),
      State('input-garage', 'value'),
      State('input-built_year', 'value'),
      State('input-floor', 'value'),
      State('input-waterfront', 'value'),
      State('input-living_area', 'value'),
      State('input-lot_area', 'value'),
      State('input-zip_code', 'value'),
      State('input-selling_month', 'value'),
      State('input-dom', 'value')]
)
def update_result(n_clicks,bed, bath, hbath, garage, built_year, floor, 
             waterfront, living_area, lot_area, zip_code, selling_month, dom):
    if int(n_clicks) > 0:
        prediction =(-39422.64)+(bed*(-261049.88))+(bath*227856.66)+\
            (hbath*15413.56)+(garage*17875.03)+(dom*274.12)+\
                (living_area*693.40)+(built_year*350.07)+(zip_code*(-34.75))    
    
        return prediction


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: If the provided suggestion solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. I see that you've asked 12 questions by now and received many useful answers. And yet you have not accepted one single answer. If you're able to write a question in here, I'm convinced that you are also able to find out how to accept an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback has its output set to a `dbc.Input` component, which does not have a property `children`. You need to either change this to `Output('result', 'value')` or use another component to display your output.

Alternatively you could change your `dbc.Input(id='result', placeholder="")`, to a `html.Div(id='result')` and then you could keep your callback function as it is.